# Can I use WP blocks in a template?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, block-editor, page-template

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this, but I have a slider I built using ACF that I placed on my home page. After this code, I want to use a WP block I built, and after that I want to put another slider. So it would look like this:

```
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
        
            <div class="row slide-area">    

              <!-- // * Slider starts -->
              <section class="slider_container_top_main">

              <!-- all slides container starts -->
              <ul class="slider_container_top">

                <?php

                      // get slider data
                      if (have_rows('slider')) :

                          while (have_rows('slider')) : the_row();

                              $slider_image = get_sub_field('slider_image');
                              $slider_headline = get_sub_field('slider_headline');
                              
                      ?>

                <!-- slide starts -->
                <li>
                  <div class="slider_container_top_img_container">            

                    <img src="<?php echo $slider_image['url'] ?>" alt="slider image" class="slider_container_top_img"
                      loading="lazy">          

                    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center top-navigation-div">
                      
                      <div class="col-lg-9 offset-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-12 black-s top-navigation-controls"><?php echo $slider_headline; ?></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!-- slide ends -->

                <?php

                  endwhile;
                  endif;
                      
                ?>

              </ul>
              <!-- all slides container ends -->

              </section>
              <!-- // * Slider ends -->
              
            </div>
            
          
        </div>
      </div>

** WP block would go here **

// And here's another slider

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
        
            <div class="row slide-area">    

              <!-- // * Slider starts -->
              <section class="slider_container_top_main">

              <!-- all slides container starts -->
              <ul class="slider_container_top">

                <?php

                      // get slider data
                      if (have_rows('slider')) :

                          while (have_rows('slider')) : the_row();

                              $slider_image = get_sub_field('slider_image');
                              $slider_headline = get_sub_field('slider_headline');
                              
                      ?>

                <!-- slide starts -->
                <li>
                  <div class="slider_container_top_img_container">            

                    <img src="<?php echo $slider_image['url'] ?>" alt="slider image" class="slider_container_top_img"
                      loading="lazy">          

                    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center top-navigation-div">
                      
                      <div class="col-lg-9 offset-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-12 black-s top-navigation-controls"><?php echo $slider_headline; ?></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!-- slide ends -->

                <?php

                  endwhile;
                  endif;
                      
                ?>

              </ul>
              <!-- all slides container ends -->

              </section>
              <!-- // * Slider ends -->
              
            </div>
            
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Is there a way to do something like this? Put WP blocks between code in a template?

Comment: Should the block be editable? If not, you can just add the final HTML to your template. If it should be editable, I would recommend converting the whole page to a block-based one and creating simple blocks for your carousels.

Comment: If you're using ACF you should look at their Blocks code, it will do this pretty easily

Comment: Should be able to replace `** WP block would go here **` with the standard loop i believe.

Comment: I would be wary that none of the code in your question has any escaping, which is a significant security issue. Don't write `<img src="<?php echo $slider_image['url'] ?>"` and just assume it's a URL, write `<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $slider_image['url'] ); ?>"` instead and guarantee it's a URL.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm pretty new to PHP. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 methods

1. `do_blocks`, takes block content as a string, parses them, renders each block, then returns the final rendered content. This is the same content in `post_content`, aka the HTML comment and the HTML tags inside it e.g. something similar to this: `echo do_blocks( '<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>Hello world.</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->');`
2. Use a block template part in a block theme. This way the entire template is blocks

Comment: Thanks, Tom, this seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the other way around, use wp block for the page and insert your code as a shortcode.

```php
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); <?php
    <h3> this is my shortcode </h3>
    ?>
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'myShortCodeName', 'my_shortcode');
```

now on wp blocks its possible to use the shortcode block and call [myShortCodeName]